# Haskell platform on 14.04

Tags: haskell

Is it right that 14.04 does not have the haskell platform avaible by the software center.

Do I need to compile it by source or is there anothe way to make this work ?

Roelof

Answer (score 10):

> These distributions offer the Haskell Platform in their package repositories. You can easily install the Haskell Platform through your distribution's native package manager.
>
> - Ubuntu
> - ...

***Source:*** http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html

[Enable `universe` repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/269282), then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem using `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`, then I just used

```
sudo apt-get install  libglew-dev libcheese7 libcheese-gtk23 libclutter- gst-2.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-0  xserver-xorg-input-all haskell-platform
```

And the problem was solved. ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/xYoA16iCQ7M))